# In Spock, how can I test the code inside withTransaction

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

In Spock, how can I test for `withTransaction` block?
For example, during the test for the code below, how can I make sure that the code inside `MyLookup.withTransaction` gets executed?

```
then:
1 * MyLookup.findValue(item)
```

And here is service class:

```
class itemService {

    static String lookUpInfo(String item){  
        MyLookup.withTransaction {
            valInfo = MyLookup.findValue(item)
        }
        return valInfo
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining or - even better - showing the classes your are trying to test, such as `MyLookup`? This is called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and is incredibly helpful for people trying to help you because then they can actually reproduce your situation and maybe offer solutions or hints about how to refactor your code.

Comment: Are you using Grails?

Comment: Yes.  Groovy Grails.

Answer (score 0):

So you can look at the PowerMock framework which enables you to test static methods see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323909/verify-static-method-call-using-powermockito-1-6?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) post as to how.

Alternatively you can wrap the static method call in your own class and mock your wrapper class to make sure the call is made.

Hope this helps.